# solve $d^2+d^3=324,d>0$ in real numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve $\quad d^2+d^3=324,\quad d>0$ in real numbers.

I was solving a Geometry problem asking me to find the diameter.

> A cylindrical container of diameter $12$ cm and height $15$ cm is filled with ice-cream. The whole icecream has to be distributed to $10$ children in equal cones with hemispherical tops. If the height of the conical portion is twice the diameter of its base, find the diameter of the ice-cream cone.

then i reached this

$ d^2+d^3=324$

Wolfram gives this answer as $\approx 6.55$

How can i find this by using pen and paper.

I have studied maths upto $12$th grade.

Comment: how did you reach that equation?

Comment: It seems that either in formulating the volume of the hemisphere or the volume of the cone, you used a formula for surface area, or just made a power of 3 into a power of 2. Note that as a sanity check, the units in your equation don't make sense: you are adding an area and a volume together.

Comment: by this i reached it. $\pi\times 6^2\times 15=10(\dfrac23\times \pi\times (\dfrac{d}{2})^2+\dfrac{\pi}{3}\times (\dfrac{d}{2})^2\times 2d)$

Comment: Volume of a hemisphere of radius $r$ is $(2/3) \pi r^3$, not $(2/3) \pi r^2$.

Comment: Your first piece appears to be the volume of the hemisphere, and it should have $(d/2)^3$, not $(d/2)^2$. So you should get an equation like $d^3 = a$ for some number $a$, which is easy to solve.

Comment: Oh i see , it was $(\dfrac{d}{2})^3$

Answer (score 1):

First we find the volume of of the cylinder of ice cream and divide it by 10.

$\pi*6^2*15=540\pi/10=54\pi$

So each cone must have a volume of $54\pi$

Using the volume for a cone and a hemisphere, we get

$1/3\pi*r^2*h+1/2*4/3\pi*r^3=54\pi$

Divide by pi and simplify:

$1/3r^2*h+2/3r^3=54$

So the problem stated that the height is twice the diameter, which would be 4 times the radius, so h=4r, giving you:

$1/3r^2*4r+2/3r^3=54$

$4/3r^3+2/3r^3=54$

Solving for $r$ gives you $r=3$, so the diameter is $6$.